# Bonding / Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, netplan, network-bonding

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a VM with 2 ethernet ports. I'm trying to bond those 2 ethernet ports, but I can't find the right way. For example, someone says without netplan, others with netplan, bond with bridge, etc.

I'm new in this, is there a way to do a simple bonding?

**Update:** I reached this point:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    eth1:
        dhcp4: false

    eth2:
        dhcp4: false

bonds:
    bond0:
        dhcp4: false
        interfaces:
        - eth1
        - eth2
        parameters:
            mode: balance-rr
            mii-monitor-interval: 100
bridges:
    br0:
        dhcp4: true
        interfaces:
        - bond0
```

And I can't get the IP  for `br0`. The same happens if I only use `bond0` without `br0`.

Thanks

Update II [image]

Comment: It is important that you have correct indentation in your netplan config. Also, you don't provide any gateway, so how would you get an IP without a gateway??

Comment: The br0 interface declares dhcp4: true, which is how it's expected to get an IP.

Comment: Can you show the output of 'ip link show'?  which of the interfaces show as 'up'?

Comment: Of course you're right, my mistake.

Comment: I've updated the post with an ifconfig after adding gateway4 , still the same no ip in br0 and if I pit a static ip also I can´t ping to br0. ( eht0 is not part of the bonding, just for conection purposes)

Answer (score 0):

As on your screenshot, you have three ethernets: `eth0, eth1, eth2` . `eth0` has an IP, so you have some config for this (ie by `ifupdown` with `/etc/network/interfaces` config).

I hope `eth1, eth2` is not connected to the same switch and network, to get this works it needs more settings.

You should check, that any other tools like `ifupdown` not used for bringing up `eth1, eth2` and `bond0`, `br0`.
Do not use this tools with netplan.
Disable `eth1, eth2` ifaces – remove lines with `auto` for `eth1, eth2`, add just one line: `iface eth1 inet manual` for each.
Or rename or delete file `/etc/network/interfaces`.

If you rename or delete `/etc/network/interfaces`, you should add config `eth0` to netplan config.

For example, in my config I have `em1, em2` ethernets. `bond0` its together, and `br0` at the top of `bond0`. `br0` gets IP via DHCP. `br0` is needed to get access to network from VMs on this server.
My config:

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    em1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
    em2:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces:
        - em1
        - em2
      macaddress: "xx:xx:xx:xx:2b:62"
      parameters:
        mode: 802.3ad
        lacp-rate: fast
        mii-monitor-interval: 100
        transmit-hash-policy: layer2+3
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
      macaddress: "xx:xx:xx:xx:2b:62"
      interfaces:
        - bond0
```

You can remove part with `bridges` and set `dhcp4: yes, dhcp6: yes` to `bond0`. This should also works, and `bond0` should get IP from DHCP.

Also I made a working config for `ifupdown2` (maybe because old `ifupdown` can't handle ifaces dependency, but `ifupdown2` can).

Comment: Why would you care if they are on the same switch?

Answer (score -1):

Based on yours and my own config, I would imagine something like this could work:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth1:
            dhcp4: false
        eth2:
            dhcp4: false
    bonds:
        bond0:
            dhcp4: false
            interfaces:
              - eth1
              - eth2
            parameters:
                mode: balance-rr
                mii-monitor-interval: 100
    bridges:
        br0:
            dhcp4: true
            gateway4: your.gate.way.addr
            interfaces:
              - bond0
```

Comment: zero requirement to manually specify a gateway when using dhcp.

Comment: I try every thing I know and could find and I can´t get DHCP to work on the bonding. and if I use static ip also I can´t ping the ip address.